# Ajax loading image error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

my question is very simple. I have drafted the code as follow for showing the loading image when the form is being posted. The loading image can be shown properly. However, it cannot hide automatically after the result is returned. May i know what is the error?

HTML

```
<div id="loading"></div>
```

Ajax

```
function email_subscribe(){
    $('#loading').html('<img src="loading.gif"> loading...');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'index.php?subscribe',
        dataType: 'html',
        data:$("#subscribe").serialize(),
        success: function (html) {
            $('#loading').html();
            eval(html);
    }});
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it cannot hide after the result is returned`? You seem to be using the getter of `html()` but not assigning it to a variable. Your use of `eval()` also has me concerned.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to remove the loading html but, why not just `.hide()` it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just calling the `.html()` method without any parameters (which serves as a *getter*). To achieve what you're looking for here, you need to at least pass in like an empty string to `set` and overwrite existing content.

```
$('#loading').html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

I also think you should not use eval....

...and yes call .html() with an argument like:

```
$('#loading').html("&nbsp;");
```

or

```
$('#loading').html(" ");
```